# C++ Pointer WHY?

Tags: c++, pointers

I was getting a little stuck on this and I needed some clarification on what is exactly going on. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out.

```
int i[][3] = {
 { 1, 2, 3 },
 { 4, 5, 6 }
};

int* pointy = &i[1][1];
int* copyPointy = pointy;

*pointy = 100;
pointy = &i[0][2];

cout << *pointy << endl;
cout << *copyPointy << endl;
```

I want to know what the following line represents/means :

```
 int* copyPointy = pointy;
```

I am trying to figure out why `*copyPointy` returns `100` rather than `3`? If `pointy` points to `copyPointy`, and if the address of `pointy`changes when the statement `pointy = &i[0][2];` is executed, then shouldn't the address of `copyPointy` change too, and thus the contents at that address?

Comment: `pointy` points first to `&i[1][1]`, and later to `&i[0][2]`. `pointy` cannot ever point to `copyPointy` as it isn't a `int**`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant doesn't *if copyPointy points to pointy then if the address of pointy changes, when pointy = &[0][2], shouldn't the address of copyPointy change too, and thus the contents at that address?

Comment: That doesn't really change anything, neither `point` nor `copyPointy` point to each other at any point(!). The type of a pointer to pointer to `int` would be `int**`, those are both `int*`.

Comment: `int a = 1; int b = a; a = 2;` Would you expect printing `b` to print 2? Pointers aren't magic. They hold addresses. Initializing one with the address held in another doesn't mean a later change to the address held in *either* does anything  to the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that a pointer's value is an address - the address of the thing it's pointing to. What a pointer's value is and what it points to are two separate things.

Let's label your lines:

```
int i[][3] = {
 { 1, 2, 3 },
 { 4, 5, 6 }
 };

 int* pointy = &i[1][1];
 int* copyPointy = pointy; // (1) 

 *pointy = 100;            // (2)
  pointy = &i[0][2];       // (3)

  cout << *pointy << endl;
  cout << *copyPointy << endl;
```

After `(1)` runs, `pointy` and `copyPointy`'s values are the same: both are the same address, namely, the address of the second element of the second array (where `5` is).

After `(2)` executes, the element at that address gets changed to 100. `pointy` and `copyPointy` both still have the same address, and so they are pointing to the same thing, which has now become the integer `100`.

After `(3)` executes, the value of `pointy` is now something else - namely, the address of the 3rd element of the 1st array (where `3` is). The value of `copyPointy` hasn't changed - it wasn't assigned to anything else - so it's still pointing to the same element it was before, namely `100`.

Thus when you print the content of the values at their respective addresses, you would expect `3` and `100`, which is what you get.

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a variable whose value is an address.

Remember this, let's go through your case:

```
int* pointy = &i[1][1];
```

`pointy` now holds the address of `i[1][1]`, i.e. `pointy` -> Address A

```
int* copyPointy = pointy;
```

Now you assign `copyPointy` the value of `pointy`, which is the address of `i[1][1]`, e.g. now `copyPointy` -> Address A and `pointy` -> Address A.

```
*pointy = 100;
pointy  = &i[0][2];
```

These statements assign the content in Address A, 100, and then change `pointy` to Address B.

It looks like `copyPointy` -> Address A, which holds 100, and `pointy` -> Address B. `copyPointy` does not change with `pointy` because you only copy the value when assigning.

And also you tag your question c++, you can let `copyPointy` 3 after you change `pointy` by using

```
int * &copyPointy = pointy;
```

which means `copyPointy` is an alias of `pointy`, once you change the value of `pointy` the value of `copyPointy` also changes.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was so clear! It makes sooo much more sense!

Answer (score 1):

This statement relates to your first question:

```
int* copyPointy = pointy;
```

This means that a copy of the value inside `pointy` is to be stored inside `copyPointy`. The value inside `pointy` was `&i[1][1]` (the address of `i[1][1]`). After this statement is executed, inside `copyPointy` will be `&i[1][1]`.

If we were to do `*copyPointy` right now, we would have `i[1][1]` which is `5`.

Now look at the following statement int the code:

```
*pointy = 100;
```

Here `*pointy = 100;` means that the integer value `100` shall replace the value at the address inside `pointy`. After this statement is executed, `i[1][1]` will be `100`.

The address inside `copyPointy`has not changed, it is still `&i[1][1]`.  But the value in `i[1][1]` has changed from `5` to `100`.  So when we do `*copyPointy` we get `i[1][1]` which is now `100`.

Finally, look at this statement:

```
pointy = &i[0][2];
```

When we execute this statement, `pointy` will have inside it a new address, namely the address of `i[0][2]` which contains the integer `3`. But the address of `copyPointy` is still `&i[1][1]` since it merely took a copy of the previous address in `pointy`.

As a result, when we do `*pointy` and `*copyPointy` at the end, we get the values at two different addresses. Respectively, the integer in `i[0][2]` and the integer in `i[1][1]`.